# Replacing Layouts using Fragments?

Tags: java, android

relatively new to all of this and this is another noob question that I would be grateful for, I've been trying to work on a new task. Currently, there is an ImageButton called Japanese on this page, and when clicked, I would like it to replace the current ScrollView layout with a new layout showing some new contents. The activity should remain the same after all as I am trying to just replace the ScrollView layout, shouldn't it? I've been thinking of a way to use fragments to achieve this but have no clue on how to do it.

The only example I can think of is Spotify's interface, if you are on the homepage and you click an image, it 'replaces' that layout to show some new songs or something, but doesn't affect the bottom navigation.

I've viewed these videos so far but am not sure if they are the right solution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FF-e6CnBwYY

[image: This is what I'm trying to achieve.]

This is my code so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbartitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Home"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/the_bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottomnavigationmenu">

</android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"> 

     [content here]

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi so I recommend using fragments to achieve this.
Create a main activity, then 2 different fragments for each of your views.
Have a look here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

If you want some code samples let me know.

Comment: Hi, so for my current codes I'll have to put them into a fragment as well? And yes a code sample would be nice to see how this all works!

Comment: No problem, I'll provide a code sample soon. But basically yes, when you create a new fragment in Android Studio, it generates a Java class (where you put the logic) and an XML file which is the layout for your fragment.